# What do I have to add to my Haskell code to work for all of the cases?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

My code is not working for example : `swapElems ([],[1,2])`
How can I fix it ?

```
swapElems :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
swapElems [] = []
swapElems [x:y:xs] = [y : x :xs]
swapElems ((x:y:s):ls) = (y:x:s): swapElems ls
swapElems [x]= [x]
```

Comment: What is `swapElems` *supposed* to do?

Comment: Swaps the first two elements of lists in a list! If a list does not contain at least two items, we will return it in its original state!

Comment: in that case, since you want to do the same thing (swap the first two elements) to each member of a list, you'll find it easier to just write that function and then `map` it over the list of lists.

Comment: I.e., define `swap' :: [a] -> [a]`, then `swapElems = fmap swap`.

Comment: @teki2021: for all sublists perform a swap, or swap the first two sublists in the "outer" list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern matching does too much. You can work with three patterns:

1. the empty list;
2. a non-empty list where the first sublist has two or more items; and
3. a non-empty list where the first list has less than two items.

You can thus define this as:

```
swapElems :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
swapElems [] = …  -- (1)
swapElems ((x:y:xs):xss) = …  -- (2)
swapElems (xs:xss) = …  -- (3)
```

It probably however makes more sense to implement a helper function:

```
swap2 :: [a] -> [a]
swap2 (x:y:xs) = …
swap2 xs = xs
```

and then work with a mapping of `swap2`:

```
swapElems :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
swapElems = map swap2
```